# Contact Form 7 Data As Attachment

Tags: attachments, plugin-contact-form-7

I want data submitted through Contact Form 7 to be sent as an attachment as opposed to text / html inside the email body.

Specifically I want  this attachment to be in CSV format, which should be relatively straight forward to format based on the contact form 7 fields, but this depends upon whether it is possible to place this text into an attachment.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why this is considered off topic. The solution to this problem is very specific to Wordpress. If someone re-opens this question I can post the solution to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Without any coding you can use the [**`Contact Form 7 to Database Extension`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) plugin which has the ability to export the posted data as CSV.

And if you are up for some coding then you can hook the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action hook with your own function to create the csv form the `$_POST` data and sent it.

Comment: Thank you, I used the *wpcf7_before_send_mail* action hook, along with the *fputcsv* php function and it worked nicely :)

Comment: @Josh know this is an oldie, but I'm now looking to do something similar. Care to share your implementation?